# Underscore template display array of objects via _.each

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm having trouble printing out a simple for each comment loop with _.template.

```
<% _.each([comments], function(i) { %>  <p><%= i %></p> <% }); %>
```

prints [object Object]

```
<% _.each([comments], function(i) { %>  <p><%= JSON.stringify(i) %></p> <% }); %>
```

prints:

```
[{"comment":"Mauris quis leo at diam molestie sagittis.","id":263,"observation_id":25}]
```

What I've tried so far:

```
<% _.each([comments], function(i) { %>  <p><%= i.comment %></p> <% }); %>
```

blank

```
<% _.each([comments], function(i) { %>  <p><%= i.get('comment') %></p> <% }); %>
```

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'get'

```
<% _.each([comments], function(i) { %>  <p><%= comment %></p> <% }); %>
```

blank

Comment: And what does `comments` contains? That's basically what's important here.

Comment: And why are you wrapping `comments` in an array? I would assume that it's already an array, right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming comments is an array on your model:

```
<% _.each(comments, function(comment) { %>  
  <p><%= comment.comment %></p> 
<% }); %>
```